# How do I run a program that uses SQL Server on a workgroup without "Running as Administrator?"

Tags: sql-server, sql-authentication

Our office has a very simple SQL Server setup. Because of our limited hardware and resources, we use a workgroup instead of a Domain Controller.

Everything is working smoothly, expect for one thing. When I use a 3rd party program (such as a CAD software) to connect to SQL Server, it always crashes unless I run the program as administrator.

I'd like to have my office computers, which are standard users, not have to run these program as administrators. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Our setup:

- Physical server is a rack server running Windows Server 2022 Standard
- SQL Server is running from Microsoft SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server Management Studio.
- Client PCs are running Windows 10 and 11. They can connect to the file servers through windows authentication, and connect to the SQL Server with SQL Server authentication. Programs will not even open to use SQL Server authentication without "running as administrator." I thought it might be a firewall thing, but I turned off firewalls. I'm sure it has to do with being a workgroup rather than a domain, but there has to be a workaround.

Help please.

I tried changing firewall and security settings, but turning off the firewall still does not allow it to connect to SQL Server. I also tried it with a different RDBMS (SQL Anywhere) and had the same issue. I believe its an issue with workgroups, but not sure how to do a workaround.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but perhaps it's a Windows DEP thing? Try adding the applications to exclude list

Comment: Don't think it's anything to do with SQL Server, probably an antivirus thing. But SQL authentication doesn't work unless either: you have a domain and using domain accounts, or you are logged in as a local user and the same user *with the same password* is on the SQL Server machine also.

Comment: Is the CAD software SOLIDWORKS? It sounds like they have a poorly designed security model, [Configuring Microsoft SQL Server](https://help.solidworks.com/2022/English/SolidWorks/install_guide/c_configure_ms_sql_server.htm), _If you install a new instance of SQL Server, you need full administrative rights to the server, and also to any client systems._ And so on...